# which type of honey is healing for us?

Tags: quran, hadith

I want to know about the type of honey which is healing fo us.detailed answer in quranic point or hadith.

Answer (score 0):

Honey have powerful healing attributes. Both the holy Quran and Hadiths refer to honey as a healer of disease.In the Quran, “And thy Lord taught the bee to build its cells in hills, on trees and in people’s habitations… there issues from within their bodies a drink of varying colors, wherein is healing for humankind.  Verily in this is a Sign for those who give thought.” 
 In Sahih Bukhari we read that the Prophet said: “Honey is a remedy for every illness and the Quran is a remedy for all illness of the mind, therefore I recommend to you both remedies, the Quran and honey.”

There are many different types of honey available each with a unique
flavor depend on the blossoms visited by the honey bees. Single varietal honeys
result when the honey bees gather nectar from the same type of flowers. This process is aided by bee_keepers who strategically place their hives in an orchard or adjacent to a single type of flower
it is difficult to suggest which one honey is best . Rather it depend on the purpose for which you take honey .Given below are some of beneficial types of honey.you can use any one honey according to your need.
1. Alfalfa(it is good for the cardio issues)
2. Avocado(it have a large amount of vitamins,anti-oxidant and minerals)
3. Blueberry(it contain more antioxidant compounds than some other lighter honeys)
4. Buckwheat(good for diabetes ,liver)
5. Clover(it is good for promoting wound healing and cholesterol)
6. Eucalyptus Honey(respiratory,anti-spasmodic and anti-inflammatory)